# SGECluster in multiple queues

Tags: dask, dask-distributed, dask-delayed

I'm using dask.distributed to launch jobs on a SGE cluster (https://jobqueue.dask.org/en/latest/generated/dask_jobqueue.SGECluster.html#dask_jobqueue.SGECluster) via dask.bags and/or dask.delayed.

Everything works nicelly. However, i may have some dask.delayed that should run in a specific queue on my SGE cluster (due to GPU availability for instance). How can I work this out on dask?

In other words, how can I define a `dask_jobqueue.SGECluster` with multiple queues and/or different resource specs?
`dask_jobqueue.SGECluster` allows me to configure one cluster setup only (one queue, one resource spec, etc..).

Thanks

Comment: I believe that there is an open issue about this on github at https://github.com/dask/dask-jobqueue/issues somewhere

Comment: Well, I couldn't find similar request.

Comment: Anyone willing to help? Thanks

Comment: I think this issue seems relevant: https://github.com/dask/dask-jobqueue/issues/304